# How can a admin lock/unlock a user registered in a mysql database using spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, roles, status, account, user-permissions

I'm working on a spring boot project which has to have an admin who can lock/unlock a user using account-status field in mysql database. This has to be done in the front end.

I have a users table with a account status field that has locked/unlocked enum where unlocked is the default value. I need an admin to lock/unlock that user depending on roles. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

These kind of tasks let spring handle it.

Use spring's UserDetails class which has a field isLocked by default.

In your UserDetails implementations, pass **true** to the following values

1. isAccountNonExpired()
2. isAccountNonLocked()
3. isCredentialsNonExpired()

For more, check the **public void check(UserDetails user)** in **AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider** class.